# Convert graph with higher functions

Tags: list, haskell, graph

I have a graph like: `[("a","b"),("a","c"),("a","d"),("b","e"),("c","f"),("d","e"),("e","f"),("e","g"),("f","d")]` and I need to convert that to:

```
[("a",["b","c","d"]),("b",["e"]) ...]
```

Because it's a college project I can only use higher functions and Data.List

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'll only give you a hint: take a look at [`Data.List.groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3agroupBy).

Comment: For use groupBy, Do I need to use `on` function?

Comment: You don't *have* to use it, but it can help.

Comment: But when I use `on` and I had an error like _Not in scope: `on'
Perhaps you meant `or' (imported from Data.List)_

Comment: I tried to do `myGroup g = map (\l -> (fst . head $ l, map snd l)) . groupBy (\x y -> x == y) . (map fst g)` but I got an error

Comment: @jorgeserrao on is fram Data.Function.

Comment: How can I do that without `on`?